# H2 and liquibase syntax error

Tags: java, oracle, h2, liquibase

I am usig liquibase for building database. And on startup of war the liquibase initializes Oracle db from application and makes it successfully. But in unit tests H2 db is used and here is a problem. Can't find smth similar in google. this is my changeset:

```
<changeSet author="Andriyanchik" id="EBS-639">
    <sql endDelimiter="/">
            CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_SET_TYPE_NUMBER
            BEFORE INSERT
            ON PROVIDER
            FOR EACH ROW
            DECLARE
                v_category_inc NUMBER;
            BEGIN
                SELECT MAX(TYPENUMBER) INTO v_category_inc FROM PROVIDER WHERE PRODUCTNAME = :NEW.PRODUCTNAME;
                IF v_category_inc is null THEN
                    :NEW.TYPENUMBER := 0;
                ELSE
                    :NEW.TYPENUMBER := v_category_inc + 1;
                END IF;
            END;
            /
        </sql>
</changeSet>
```

In H2 I am getting error:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_SET_TYPE_NUMBER..."
expected "QUEUE, NOWAIT, AS, CALL"; SQL statement:
```

Comment: H2 does not support PL/SQL - there is no way you can run this against a H2 database (or _any_ database that is not Oracle)